# com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment in android google map not working in some lollipop devices

Tags: android

Error as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dapl.stockup/com.dapl.stockup.activity.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class fragment
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class fragment
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:767)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2158)
      at com.dapl.stockup.activity.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:50)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706) 
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Configuration android.content.res.Resources.getConfiguration()' on a null object reference
      at android.view.SurfaceView.init(SurfaceView.java:231)
      at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>(SurfaceView.java:193)
      at maps.V.x.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at maps.V.v.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at maps.D.u.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at maps.D.u.a(Unknown Source)
      at maps.ad.ae.a(Unknown Source)
      at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
      at maps.ad.M.a(Unknown Source)
      at wd.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1065)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:376)
      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2158) 
      at com.dapl.stockup.activity.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:50) 
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    FragmentManager manager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) myContext.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment));
    trans.remove(supportMapFragment);
    try {
        if (trans != null && supportMapFragment != null) {
            trans.commit();
        }
    }catch (Exception ex) {}

}
```

Comment: It's not working. I am facing map opening crash issue only on some lolipop devices like Redmi note 3.

Comment: Please help me asap

Comment: class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" not working while add google map v2 in existing project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where it only crashes on my Xiaomi testing device. Have you tried enabling android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in the Android Manifest file. Would be something like this:

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/Logo" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

It did the trick for mine. No more crashing on trying to open a map :D